# Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of stopping times. If $\limsup_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is finite, then it is a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, solution-verification, stopping-times

I'm doing this exercise from my lecture note of martingale theory:

> Let $I \subseteq \mathbb N$ and $(\mathcal F_n)$ be a filtration. A random variable $T$ taking values in $I \cup \{\infty\}$ is a stopping time if and only if $\{T = n\} \in \mathcal F_n$ for all $n \in I$.
>
> $\textbf{Proposition:}$ Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of stopping times. If $T = \limsup_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is finite, then $T$ is a stopping time. Similarly, If $T = \liminf_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is finite, then $T$ is a stopping time.

Could you please verify if my proof is correct or contains logical mistake? Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:**

We need two lemmas:

> $\textbf{Lemma 1:}$ If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of stopping times such that $T = \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$ exists and is finite. Then $T$ is a stopping time.
>
> $\textbf{Lemma 2:}$ If $S,T$ are stopping time, then so are $S \vee T$ and $S\wedge T$.

First, we prove that $\inf_{k \ge N} T_k$ is a stopping time for any $N \in \mathbb N$. Define a sequence $(X_n)$ by $X_0 = T_N$ and $X_{n+1} = X_n \wedge T_{N+n+1}$. By $\textbf{Lemma 2}$, $(X_n)$ is a sequence of stopping times such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \inf_{k \ge N} T_k$. Then, by $\textbf{Lemma 1}$, $\inf_{k \ge N} T_k$ is a stopping time.

On the other hand, $T = \limsup_{n \to \infty} T_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \ge n} T_k$. By $\textbf{Lemma 1}$ again, $T$ is a stopping time.

In a similar manner, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Well first there is a little mistake as "lim sup" is the infimum of the sup for k>N of $T_k$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior  but as you have to prove the result for the "lim inf" which is the opposite it is not so bad. In any case I would say that you need to add a little more effort and details on the claim $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \inf_{k \ge N} T_k$ exists and is finite (for the "lim inf" case off course) from the hypotheses.

Comment: Hi @TheBridge, I've added detail on $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \inf_{m \ge 0} T_m$ and posted it as an answer below. Could you please check if it's fine now. Actually, my lemmas do not require each term of the sequence of stopping times to be finite, so I think the fact that $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m$ is finite or not is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I see it (using your lemmas 1 and 2)

Let's look at the "$\liminf$" case :
By hypothesis(and [wiki page section 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Examples_2)) :

$$\liminf _n T_n =\sup_n \inf_{k>n} T_k=T$$ exists and is finite.

So for some $n_0$ big enough we have for all $n>n_0$:
$$I_n =\inf_{k>n} T_k$$ is finite. 
Then we can use your line of argument to prove that $I_n$ is a stopping time. for every such $n$, but please pay attention to the indexation.

Defining  $I^p_n = T_n\wedge ... \wedge T_p$ and using lemma 2, $I^p_n$ is a stopping time for every $p$. As $\lim_p I^p_n= I_n$ is finite, we are now ok to use lemma 1, and conclude that $I_n$ is a stopping time.

Let's finish the job. You can observe that $T= \sup_n I_n = \lim_n I_n$ (observe that $I_n$ is increasing) exists and is finite where we know that $I_n$ is a sequence of stopping times.(we can restart the sequence $I_n$ at n_0 if needed). So we can  re-use lemma 1 directly to conclude that $T$ is a stopping time.

The "$\limsup$" case is treated symmetrically.

Comment: Is your initial formula $\{\limsup T_n = k\}= \bigcap_{N>0} \bigcup_{n>N} \{T_n = k\}$ correct?

Comment: It is correct  for sequence of sets $X_n$, i.e. $\limsup \{X_n\}= \bigcap_{N>0} \bigcup_{n>N} \{X_n\}$ (in fact the very definition of lim sup for a sequence sets)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.

Comment: In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557071/368425) @Kavi Rama Murthy gave a counter example of $f^{-1} (\alpha) = \bigcap_{m=0}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty f_n^{-1} (\alpha)$ where $f = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n$. Actually, I'm very confused.

Comment: Well what he said is perfectly correct, that is why I withdrew my erroneous comments. Lim sup of sets is not the same as pre image of lim sup of functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Until now, I understand what you meant in your previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

From @TheBridge, I supplement my original proof with details here.

---

**My attempt:** We need two lemmas:

> $\textbf{Lemma 1:}$ If $(T_n)$ is a sequence of stopping times such that $T = \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n$ exists and is finite. Then $T$ is a stopping time.
>
> $\textbf{Lemma 2:}$ If $(S_n)_{m=0}^n$ is a finite sequence of stopping times, then $\max_{0 \le m \le n} S_m$ and $\min_{0 \le m \le n} S_m$ are stopping time.

First, we prove that $\inf_{m \ge n} T_m$ is a stopping time for any $n \in \mathbb N$. It suffices to prove that $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m$ is a stopping time. Define a sequence $(X_n)$ by $X_{n} = \min_{0 \le m \le n} T_m$. Clearly, $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m \le X_{n}$. Given $(\epsilon, \omega) \in \mathbb R^+ \times \Omega$, there is $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m (\omega) \le T_k (\omega) < \inf_{m \ge 0} T_m (\omega)+ \epsilon$. Then $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m (\omega) \le X_k (\omega) < \inf_{m \ge 0} T_m (\omega)+ \epsilon$. It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = \inf_{m \ge 0} T_m (\omega)$ and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \inf_{m \ge 0} T_m$. By $\textbf{Lemma 2}$, $(X_n)$ is a sequence of stopping times. Then, by $\textbf{Lemma 1}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is also a stopping time. Hence $\inf_{m \ge 0} T_m$ is a stopping time.

On the other hand, $T = \liminf_{n \to \infty} T_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{m \ge n} T_m$. By $\textbf{Lemma 1}$ again, $T$ is a stopping time. In a similar manner, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} T_n$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Hi @TheBridge, could you please send me a wikipedia link mentioning $\{\limsup T_n = k\}= \cap_{N>0} \cup_{n>N} \{T_n = k\}$?