# The reasoning/intuition behind $f^{-1} (\alpha) = \bigcap_{m=0}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty f_n^{-1} (\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb N$. We define $f:X \to \mathbb N$ by $f(x) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n (x)$. Then we write $f = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n$. Assume that $f(x)$ is finite for all $x \in X$.

In this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551306/let-t-n-be-a-sequence-of-stopping-times-if-limsup-n-to-infty-t-n-is#comment7305740_3551941), @TheBridge said that $$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb N:f^{-1} (\alpha) = \bigcap_{m=0}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m+1}^\infty f_n^{-1} (\alpha)$$

Could you please explain the reasoning/intuition to get this formula? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $f_n(x)=1$ for all $x$ when $n$ is even and $f_n(x)=2$ for all $x$ when $n$ is odd. Then $f(x)=2$ for all $x$. So $x \in \cap_{m=0}^{\infty}\cup_{n=m+1}^{\infty}f_n^{-1}\{1\}$ for any $x$ but $x \notin f^{-1} \{1\}$ for any $x$.

Comment: In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3553249/368425), you said that *However what is said in the comment you have quoted is correct. You are forgetting the fact that they are considering integer valued variables there*. Could you please reconcile this difference?

Comment: @Navier_Stokes I was mistaken. I have corrected the earlier answer. The result is false even in the case of integer valued functions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification!